# mat-checkbox disabled on undefined

Tags: angular

checkboxes which I want to lock against each other

```
<div>
    <mat-checkbox color="primary" [(ngModel)]="data.timer.onSunrise"
        [(disabled)]="data.timer.onDisable || data.timer.onSunset || data.timer.offSunrise"><h4>bei Sonnenaufgang</h4></mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox color="primary" [(ngModel)]="data.timer.onSunset"
        [(disabled)]="data.timer.onDisable || data.timer.onSunrise || data.timer.offSunset"><h4>bei Sonnenuntergang</h4></mat-checkbox>
</div>

<div>
    <mat-checkbox color="primary" [(ngModel)]="data.timer.offSunrise"
       [(disabled)]="data.timer.offDisable || data.timer.offSunset || data.timer.onSunrise"><h4>bei Sonnenaufgang</h4></mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox color="primary" [(ngModel)]="data.timer.offSunset"
       [(disabled)]="data.timer.offDisable || data.timer.offSunrise || data.timer.onSunset"><h4>bei Sonnenuntergang</h4></mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

When I open the Dialog with some Values from DB... (console.log() shows me e.g. onSunset is undefined) the checkbox are disabled, even though onSunset has no value (undefined)

When I change the directive from [()] to () it works. it's not longer disabled. But.. it's one Way! There is no locking function anymore

```
<div>
 <mat-checkbox color="primary" [(ngModel)]="data.timer.onSunrise"
 (disabled)="data.timer.onDisable || data.timer.onSunset || data.timer.offSunrise"><h4>bei 
  Sonnenaufgang</h4></mat-checkbox>
<mat-checkbox color="primary" [(ngModel)]="data.timer.onSunset"
(disabled)="data.timer.onDisable || data.timer.onSunrise || data.timer.offSunset"><h4>bei 
  Sonnenuntergang</h4></mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Comment: Disabled is input property, It will not work as two way binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. i have a soultion.
The problem was that he write the true and false as a String in my Database.. an when the ([disabled]) has any string its always true!

with this function i could solve my problem. thx anyway

```
checkIfChecked(data):string|boolean{
  console.log(data)
  if(data === "" || data === "false" || data === false || data === null || data === undefined) {
     return null

  }else{
    return true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you using `disabled` property in angular with two way binding. It isnt going to work as two way binding. `diabled` is an input property and it will not working `[(ngModel)]` annotation. For your specific case I suggest to get the logic in to the controller and define the disabling logic there. For example

**In component.html:**

```
<div>
 <mat-checkbox color="primary" [(ngModel)]="data.timer.onSunrise"
 (disabled)="(disabled)="disableCheckBoxes(onSunrise.value,onSunset.value)" #onSunrise><h4>bei 
  Sonnenaufgang</h4></mat-checkbox>

<mat-checkbox color="primary" [(ngModel)]="data.timer.onSunset"
(disabled)="disableCheckBoxes(onSunrise.value,onSunset.value)" #onSunset><h4>bei 
  Sonnenuntergang</h4></mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

**In component.ts:**

```
disableCheckBoxes(onSunrise?:any,onSunset?:any){
      if(onSunrise.value){
        return true;
       } else if(onSunset.value) {
          return true;
     }
}
```

Similarly you can handle the logics in controller and return result via events like `click` event specific scenarios.

Similary you can use the access a HTML element is using Angulars `ElementRef`. You may read more about that [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef).

Another approach is to use the Angulars Reactive form methodology Please find reference for reative forms [here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)